# Simulate MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, testing

Is there a way to test the MySQL queries, without modifying my database?

For example, can I run a `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 101` without actual delete anything? What about `INSERT` and `UPDATE`?

TY

Comment: Why do you need to test them?

Comment: @Pekka웃  To manually check that an update is doing what you think it should do before you actually do it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could start a transaction before running your queries and then rollback after running them. Note that to do this you'll require InnoDB or XtraDb tables (won't work on MyISAM).

To start a transaction send to MySQL the following statement:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

And at the end of your queries run the following statement:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Your database will never be modified from the point of view of other connections. Your current connection will see the changes until ROLLBACK, and after that the original state will be restored.

Comment: Alright, now if I decide I like the results, how do I save them? `END TRANSACTION;`?  Geez, now I have to go all the way to Google... *wanders back* The answer was [`COMMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html).

Comment: @Zenexer, what about just executing the same query again without `START TRANSACTION;` and `ROLLBACK;` ?

Comment: @Black You could, but COMMIT is easier. Also, you’re not guaranteed to get the exact same results if you run the query again, whereas with COMMIT, what you see is what you get.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to see how many rows would be deleted why not substitute 'delete' with 'select count(*)'?

Answer (score 2):

Copy your database to a test-database or auto-generate a import-script. Than you can test whatever you want on the test-database and restore it again using the script or import.